# C# (language only) compiler

Tags: c#

I am looking for an option to compile C# syntax to native code (or maybe to C++?). I am not interested in having all the libraries that are officially part of the language, just being able to write programs the same as I write my C++ programs, but using language constructs such as partial classes, properties, lambdas, generics, etc.

1. Is there such a thing?
2. If there isn't, is such a thing even possible, or am I misunderstanding something fundamental about C#?

Comment: If you read the C# spec, some language feature are tied in to the BCL. You can't completely decouple them (say `IDisposable` and the `using` statement).

Comment: C# compiles to intermediate language, which is then executed by the .NET virtual machine. There are no libraries 'part of the language', the libraries provided by .NET are part of the BCL/FCL and are standardized by ISO.

Comment: @knittl I meant without (most of) the standard libraries. I assume minimal things like `Array` and `String` can be included without having to write the whole BCL/FCL/CLR/whatever it is called.

Comment: @Oded you can't decouple from the BCL, but you can in theory replace the BCL.  You can remove the reference to mscorlib when you compile, and then you become responsible for providing certain required types, such as `Object`, `Type`, `Array`, `String`, etc.  Also, the using statement is a compiler construct; it has nothing to do with the BCL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly the closest thing to what you want is the [Vala programming language](http://live.gnome.org/Vala).
It is heavily inspired by C# and compiles to C, which is then compiled by a traditional C compiler.

It has partial classes, properties, lambdas, generics, etc, as you say, but it's not C#.

Also check out [IL2CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IL2CPU) which translates IL to machine code. Maybe it can be used on .NET assemblies.

Comment: Re: IL2CPU, you can use the mono runtime (`mkbundle` or `mono --aot`) to precompile into native images that don't depend on a CLR or runtime.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps

NGen.exe

[see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/us-en/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx)

Comment: This just pre-compiles the byte code. It doesn't create s stand-alone .exe that can be run without the framework.

Comment: @baruch - Why would you write C# code that doesn't require the Framework.  Just use C/C++ at that point.

Comment: @Ramhound Since the language has many useful features. I listed a few of them in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The standard csc.exe compiler can compile without using the BCL.  See the reference for the `/nostdlib` switch: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa13yay7.aspx

In part, it says:

"Use this option if you want to define or create your own System namespace and objects."

Silverlight projects use this, for example.